# Use dropdownlistfor with foreach in Asp.Net MVC View?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, foreach, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a View with a foreach loop for a list property of the model. Now, I want to be able to let the user set the value of each of the items in the list using a dropdownlist. But I'm not sure how to do that. I've used something like this when it is not in a foreach loop:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Level, new SelectList(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, Model.Level))
```

But how do I do this when I need to reference item.Level in the loop instead? Here's my View code:

```
<div id="formDiv">
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Ny arbetserfarenhet</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    @*<th></th>*@
                    <th>
                        Program
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Nivå
                    </th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model) {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @item.Program.Name
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            @item.Level
                        </td>
                    </tr>
}
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have a View with a foreach loop for a list property of the mode

I would recommend you to avoid writing loops in your views in favor of editor templates. So:

```
@model IEnumerable<AppName.Models.ModelName>
<div id="formDiv">
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Ny arbetserfarenhet</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Program
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Nivå
                    </th>
                </tr>
                @Html.EditorForModel()
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    }
</div>
```

and in the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplate/ModelName.cshtml`):

```
@model AppName.Models.ModelName
<tr>
    <td>@Model.Program.Name</td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            model => model.Level, 
            new SelectList(
                Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new { Value = x, Text = x }), 
                "Value", 
                "Text"
            )
        )
    </td>
</tr>
```

So the editor template will be rendered for each element in your model (which is a collection of some type). The important part is that the editor template must be located in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` and named `XXX.cshtml` where `XXX` is the type name used in your main view model collection.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Is the reason for not using for loops that it is just more elegant like this, or some other reason? I could use it, but had to change the selectlist to the same syntax I had before, I got something strange out in the list as value and text, otherwise it worked fine!

Comment: @Anders Svensson, many reasons: cleaner views, less code, strongly typed helpers, no need to worry about generating proper id and names for binding back, ...

Comment: Ok, thanks! In any case, I realized I had to categorize items as well... which makes this a little more complicated. If you feel up to it, you're welcome to take a look at my follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433710/group-a-collection-in-mvc-view-and-update-model-in-controller

Comment: Also, using a `DropDownListFor` currently does not work well within a loop. There's an open issue for this: [link](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8311). This problem does not exist with editor templates.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.Level, new SelectList(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, item.Level))
```

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Level, new SelectList(Model.level as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "VALUE_FIELD", "TEXT_FIELD", YOUR PROPERTY NAME)
```

Comment: It's not the selectlist that's the problem, it's the fact that the dropdownlist is in a foreach loop, so I can't use the model => model.Level syntax...

Answer (score 0):

MVC will create the loop.  Just use an editor template, partial view in special folder, and the rest works like magic.

**Editor Template**

```
@model Models.AdditionalAccountingLine
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsRequired)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FieldValue, new SelectList(@Model.FieldValueOptions, "Key", "Value"), "")
```

**View**

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.AdditionalAccountingLines);
```